# Qual a melhor forma de comparar dois valores diferentes no SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Como posso escolher qual opção utilizar para comparar valores diferentes em duas tabelas?

Eu conheço essas opções para comparar valores diferentes em duas tabelas

- <> exemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 <> coluna2;`
- != exemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 != coluna2;`
- NOT exemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE NOT (coluna1 = coluna2);`
- IS DISTINCT exemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 IS DISTINCT FROM coluna2;`

Mas não estou certo de quando devo usar cada uma dessas opções. Eu gostaria de entender as diferenças e em que casos é apropriado utilizar cada uma delas. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? se possível, inclua exemplos específicos e situações em que cada uma delas pode ser vantajosa ou desvantajosa.

Comment: Até onde sei `c1 <> c2` e `c1 != c2` são "iguais". Não vejo muitos motivos para usar o `NOT (c1 = c2)` visto que pode usar os outros dois comandos acima. Quanto ao `IS DISTINCT` eu não conheço, não saberia dizer se ele é usado em algum caso mais específico

Comment: Então idependente do caso o recomendando é usar `c1 <> c2 `e `c1 != c2` certo? em questão de perfomance tbm?

Comment: O not() pode ser usado quando existe uma regra complexa e se quer o inverso ex: not (user='admin' and tipo = ' abc' and dia='terça') mas recomendo usar com critério

Comment: Referente ao uso `c1 <> c2` e `c1 != c2` acredito que essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-t-sql) possa te ajudar. Desconsiderei a possibilidade que o @Motta citou e ele está certo nisso, embora muitas vezes você acabe filtrando esses requisitos em outros lugares já

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operadores de comparação como `"<>", "!=", "NOT" e "IS DISTINCT"` são usados para comparar valores em duas tabelas diferentes no SQL. Cada um desses operadores tem suas diferenças sutis e é importante entender em que situações é apropriado usá-los.

`"<>"` é o operador padrão de desigualdade no SQL. Ele retorna verdadeiro se os valores comparados são diferentes. outro ponto a se observar é que o operador `"<>"` e retorna NULL se um ou ambos os valores são nulos.
`"!="` é outro operador de desigualdade no SQL. É uma alternativa ao operador `"<>"` e funciona de forma semelhante. No entanto, o uso do operador `"<>"` é mais comum, outra coisa que pode ser levado em consideração é o padrão projeto que esta sendo usado mantendo boas práticas.
O operador `"!="` retorna NULL se um ou ambos os valores são nulos.

**Operadores `"<>" e "!="` não são null-safe**

`"NOT"` é um operador lógico que é usado para inverter uma booleano. Vamos supor que vamos usar para comparar valores em duas tabelas, a expressão booleana seria "coluna1 = coluna2". O operador "NOT" inverte o resultado dessa expressão;

`"IS DISTINCT"` sinceramente nunca vi sendo utilizado (ou deve ser muito pouco utilizado), [pelo que li aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)!
é um operador que foi introduzido como recurso *T151 do SQL:1999* e sua negação legível, `"IS NOT DISTINCT FROM"`, foi incluída como recurso *T152 do SQL:2003*. O objetivo desses operadores é garantir que o resultado da comparação de dois valores seja True ou False, garantindo ser `NULL-safe`

por exemplo:

```
SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        resultado -> 1, 1, 0
```

O `"<=>"` operador é equivalente ao `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`  SQL padrão.

Espero que assim tenha ajudado a entender um pouco sobre a diferença entre eles :)

Referência [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)